# CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM returns half of what native camera app does (and real image has)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 which allows 8x zoom with its' native camera app.  However, CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM returns a value of 4.  When capturing a photo in RAW mode and performing the demosaic manually the resulting image definition is as it would be at 8x zoom.  However there appears to be no way to achieve the full zoom in our app's viewfinder.